# How to add an object?

Tags: modeling, objects

I can't find the option to add a new object then new texture and image. I am trying to create a 3D map from a heightmap image.
I have watched a few tutorials but the one that shows how to add a new object is for a different version with a different layout.

Answer (score 2):

To add a new object, you can

- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> in the 3D view and then select the object you want to add.

  [image]
- Press *Add* at the bottom of the 3D view and then select the object you want to add.

  [image: Add menu]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, or change the tab on the Toolbar to "Create" and then select the Plane primitive.

When creating a mesh with a heightmap you will want to first subdivide it a couple of times by pressing <kbd>W</kbd> and then selecting the Subdivide option. When you have pressed the Subdivide button you can either press <kbd>F6</kbd> to bring up the options menu or make sure you have the toolbar activated (the one on the left) by pressing <kbd>T</kbd>, both will provide you with the same resources. After you've pressed <kbd>F6</kbd> or if you are looking at the bottom of the Toolbar you will see options for the subdivision menu. Crank up the number of cuts to something like 30-50, depending on the detail you want.

Once that's done, go to the Modifiers panel (the wrench icon to the left hand side of the UI) and add a subsurf modifier (or press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>2</kbd>/<kbd>3</kbd>depending on the level of subdivisions you want) to get even more detail.

After you have added the subsurf modifier, add a Displace modifier. Press the New texture button and then click on the checkered board button in the same row as the wrench one. Once there, change the type to Image or Movie. After that you want to press the Open button and select your heightmap, and you should be set. If it is effecting your mesh too much, you can turn down the Strength parameter in the displace modifier.

Oh, and if it isn't working, try to UV Unwrap your plane first. You do this by making sure you are in edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then selecting everything with <kbd>A</kbd>, and then press the <kbd>U</kbd> button. Also make sure that the Subsurf modifier is at the top of the stack.

I hope I didn't "overanswer" your question, and I also hope I formatted it okay. I'm new to the site! :)

Comment: Welcome :) If you need any help formatting, there is a comprehensive guide [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).